Please help me understand the linear operator
Help me figure out the problem, please
On a linear space of dimension 4 over a field $\mathbb R$, a class of linear operators $C$ is defined. The class $C$ consists of all operators with the following property:
For any operator $A$ from the class $C$, the following holds:

All eigenvalues ​​of $A$ are real.
In one of the bases of the original space $\phi: \mathrm{rank}(A_{\varphi}) = 2$ and $\mathrm{tr}(A_{\varphi}A_{\varphi}^\intercal)=5$, where $A_{\varphi}$ is the matrix of $A$ in the basis $\phi$.

The basis $\phi$ is unique for each operator from $C$.
Find $\sup_{A \in C} |\lambda(A)|$ and $\inf_{A\in C} |\lambda(A)|$ where $\lambda(A)$ is the maximum eigenvalue of $A$.
I reasoned that we have two cases. The first case is when the basis of the space $\phi$ coincides with the eigenbasis of the linear operator, then the matrix $A$ can be brought to a diagonal form, on the diagonal of which the eigenvalues ​​of the linear operator will stand.Then, according to the Frobenius norm, we obtain a matrix $A$ such that:
\begin{bmatrix}λ1&0\\0&\sqrt{5-λ1^2}\end{bmatrix}
Or like this:
\begin{bmatrix}λ1&0\\0&-\sqrt{5-λ1^2}\end{bmatrix}
Then the lower and upper bounds of the eigenvalue will be equal to $-\sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{5}$.
The second case is when the linear operator has two identical eigenvalues ​​and they do not form an eigenbasis of the linear operator. Then in this case the matrix A will be:
\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{λ1}&\sqrt{5-2λ1}\\0&\sqrt{λ1}\end{bmatrix}
In this case, the lower and upper bounds of the eigenvalue will be $0$ and $\sqrt{5}$.
Then the final answer will be the lower bound $-\sqrt{5}$ and the upper bound $\sqrt{5}$, but this is not the correct answer. The lower bound should be $0$. Please explain why this is so?

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

The absolute value $|\lambda(A)|$ is always nonnegative, so a negative answer does not make sense.
